# Create a portable version of the desktop app in PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, anaconda, desktop-application

I have made a UI in QtCreator 5. Then, I converted UI-file "Odor.ui" into "ui-main.py". Then I used Anaconda framework to write a computational part in Upiter Notebook. When, I compile this code

```
import os
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy
import scipy.stats
import xlsxwriter
import re
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, qApp, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QFileDialog, QMessageBox, QTableWidgetItem, QHeaderView
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QEvent, QObject
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from ui_main import Ui_MainWindow
from os import walk
from os.path import expanduser as ospath
import glob
from time import gmtime, strftime




class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):


def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
    qApp.installEventFilter(self)
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.dataChooseBtn.clicked.connect(self.selectFile)

    self.saveSample_btn.clicked.connect(self.saveSample)

    self.data_processing.clicked.connect(self.process)

    self.string_processing.clicked.connect(self.processString)

    self.saveSampleString.clicked.connect(self.saveSampleStr)

    self.refreshSample()
    self.refreshSamples.clicked.connect(self.refreshSample)

    self.refreshSample_2()
    self.refreshSamples_2.clicked.connect(self.refreshSample_2)

    self.show()



def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
    if event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.close()
    return super(MyMainWindow, self).eventFilter(obj, event)


@pyqtSlot()
def accept(self):
    textboxValue = self.paramInput_field_2.text()
    QMessageBox.information(self, 'Message', "Значения параметрического столбца: " + textboxValue, QMessageBox.Ok, QMessageBox.Ok)



def selectFile(self):
    self.fileName = None
    options = QFileDialog.Options()
    options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
    fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Выберите стандартизированную выборку", "./Unprocessed samples","All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)", options=options)
    if fileName:
        self.fileName = fileName






def process(self):

    sample_param = pd.read_excel(self.fileName, header = None, sheetname = 1)
    param = sample_param[0].tolist()


    sample = pd.read_excel(self.fileName, sheetname = 0)

    list_of_index = []
    for i in range(len(sample.columns)):
        sample2 = sample.iloc[:, lambda sample: [i]]
        sample2 = sample2.columns[0]
        list_of_index.append(sample2)
    list_of_index   

    fulllist = []
    for i in list_of_index:
        sample3 = sample[i].tolist()
        fulllist.append(sample3)

    fulllist_percent = []
    column_percent = []
    len(fulllist)
    for i in range(len(fulllist)):
        for j in range(len(fulllist[i])):
            percent_rank = scipy.stats.percentileofscore(fulllist[i], fulllist[i][j])
            column_percent.append(percent_rank)
        fulllist_percent.append(column_percent)
        column_percent = []

    fulllist_rank = []
    for i in range(len(fulllist)):
        rank = len(fulllist[i]) - scipy.stats.rankdata(fulllist[i]) + 1
        fulllist_rank.append(rank)







    param_rank = scipy.stats.rankdata(param).astype(int)

    column_corr = []
    for i in range(len(fulllist)):
        correlation = scipy.stats.spearmanr(param_rank[::-1], fulllist_rank[i])
        column_corr.append(correlation[0])

    fulllist_click = []
    for j in range (len(fulllist_percent)):
        middle = []
        if column_corr[j] > 0:
            for i in range(len(fulllist_percent[j])):
                solve = column_corr[j] * fulllist_percent[j][i]
                middle.append(solve)
        else:
            for i in range (len(fulllist_percent[j])):    
                solve = abs(column_corr[j]) * (100 - fulllist_percent[j][i])
                middle.append(solve)
        fulllist_click.append(middle)

    list_of_rowsumm = []
    rowsumm = 0
    fulllist_clickT = numpy.asarray(fulllist_click).T.tolist()

    for i in range(len(fulllist_clickT)):
        rowsumm = sum(fulllist_clickT[i])
        list_of_rowsumm.append(rowsumm)

    percent_rowsumm = []
    for i in list_of_rowsumm:
        x = scipy.stats.percentileofscore(list_of_rowsumm, i)
        percent_rowsumm.append(x)  

    validity = scipy.stats.pearsonr(list_of_rowsumm, param)
    validity = validity[0]

    additional_info = []
    additional_info.append(list_of_rowsumm)
    additional_info.append(percent_rowsumm)
    additional_info.append(param)



    self.fulllist = fulllist
    self.fulllist_percent = fulllist_percent
    self.fulllist_click = fulllist_click
    self.additional_info = additional_info
    self.validity = validity


    return self.fulllist, self.fulllist_percent, self.fulllist_click, self.additional_info, self.validity



def saveSample(self):


    options = QFileDialog.Options()
    options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
    fileNameSave, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,"Сохранить данные выборки","./Samples","Excel files (*.xlsx)", options=options)

    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(fileNameSave + ' ['+ str(round(self.validity, 3)) + ', ' + str(len(self.fulllist)) + ', ' + str(len(self.fulllist[0])) + ']' + ".xlsx")
    worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet()
    worksheet2 = workbook.add_worksheet()
    worksheet3 = workbook.add_worksheet()
    worksheet4 = workbook.add_worksheet()

    row = 0

    for col, data in enumerate(self.fulllist):
        worksheet1.write_column(row, col, data)
    for col, data in enumerate(self.fulllist_percent):
        worksheet2.write_column(row, col, data)   
    for col, data in enumerate(self.fulllist_click):
        worksheet3.write_column(row, col, data) 
    for col, data in enumerate(self.additional_info):
        worksheet4.write_column(row, col, data)

    workbook.close()

def processString(self):

    check = self.stringInput_field.toPlainText()
    check = [float(i) for i in check.replace(',', '.').split()]


    index = self.sampleChoose_list.selectedIndexes()[0].row()
    sample_path = self.sample_directory[1][index]

    sample_param = pd.read_excel(ospath(sample_path), header = None, sheetname = 3)
    param = sample_param[2].tolist()
    param_rank = scipy.stats.rankdata(param).astype(int)


    sample_2 = pd.read_excel(ospath(sample_path), header = None, sheetname = 0)

    fulllist_new = []
    for i in range(len(sample_2.columns)):
        column_new = sample_2[i].tolist()
        fulllist_new.append(column_new)
    for i in range(len(check)):
        fulllist_new[i][0] = check[i]


    fulllist_percent_new = []
    column_percent_new = []
    for i in range(len(fulllist_new)):
        for j in range(len(fulllist_new[i])):
            percent_rank = scipy.stats.percentileofscore(fulllist_new[i], fulllist_new[i][j])
            column_percent_new.append(percent_rank)
        fulllist_percent_new.append(column_percent_new)
        column_percent_new = []






    fulllist_rank_new = []
    for i in range(len(fulllist_new)):
        rank = len(fulllist_new[i]) - scipy.stats.rankdata(fulllist_new[i]) + 1
        fulllist_rank_new.append(rank)

    column_corr_new = []
    for i in range(len(fulllist_new)):
        correlation = scipy.stats.spearmanr(param_rank[::-1], fulllist_rank_new[i])
        column_corr_new.append(correlation[0])


    fulllist_click_new = []
    for j in range (len(fulllist_percent_new)):
        middle = []
        if column_corr_new[j] > 0:
            for i in range(len(fulllist_percent_new[j])):
                solve = column_corr_new[j] * fulllist_percent_new[j][i]
                middle.append(solve)
        else:
            for i in range (len(fulllist_percent_new[j])):    
                solve = abs(column_corr_new[j]) * (100 - fulllist_percent_new[j][i])
                middle.append(solve)
        fulllist_click_new.append(middle)

    check_click = []
    for i in range(len(check)):
        if column_corr_new[i] > 0:
            click = fulllist_percent_new[i][0] * column_corr_new[i]
            check_click.append(click) 
        elif column_corr_new[i] < 0:
            click = abs(column_corr_new[i]) * (100 - fulllist_percent_new[i][0])
            check_click.append(click) 
    len(check_click)

    list_of_rowsumm_new = []
    rowsumm = 0
    fulllist_click_newT = numpy.asarray(fulllist_click_new).T.tolist()
    for i in range(len(fulllist_click_newT)):
        rowsumm = sum(fulllist_click_newT[i])
        list_of_rowsumm_new.append(rowsumm)

    percent_rowsumm_new = []
    for i in list_of_rowsumm_new:
        x = scipy.stats.percentileofscore(list_of_rowsumm_new, i)
        percent_rowsumm_new.append(x)


    validity_new = scipy.stats.pearsonr(list_of_rowsumm_new[1:], param[1:])
    validity_new = validity_new[0]
    validity_list = []
    validity_list.append(validity_new)



    additional_info_new = []
    additional_info_new.append(list_of_rowsumm_new)
    additional_info_new.append(percent_rowsumm_new)
    additional_info_new.append(validity_list)
    additional_info_new.append(param)



    self.fulllist_new = fulllist_new
    self.fulllist_percent_new = fulllist_percent_new
    self.fulllist_click_new = fulllist_click_new
    self.additional_info_new = additional_info_new
    self.validity_new = validity_new


    return self.fulllist_new, self.fulllist_percent_new, self.fulllist_click_new, self.additional_info_new, self.validity_new

def saveSampleStr(self):

    time = strftime("%d:%m:%Y %H-%M", gmtime())
    options = QFileDialog.Options()
    options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
    fileNameSave, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,"Сохранить обработанную строку","./Processed","Excel files (*.xlsx)", options=options)


    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(fileNameSave + ' (' + time + ')' + ".xlsx")
    worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet()
    worksheet2 = workbook.add_worksheet()
    worksheet3 = workbook.add_worksheet()
    worksheet4 = workbook.add_worksheet()

    row = 0

    for col, data in enumerate(self.fulllist_new):
        worksheet1.write_column(row, col, data)
    for col, data in enumerate(self.fulllist_percent_new):
        worksheet2.write_column(row, col, data)   
    for col, data in enumerate(self.fulllist_click_new):
        worksheet3.write_column(row, col, data) 
    for col, data in enumerate(self.additional_info_new):
        worksheet4.write_column(row, col, data)

    workbook.close()

def refreshSample(self): 
    sample_directory = []
    sample_files = []
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk('./Samples'):
        filenames = [f for f in filenames if not f[0] == '.']
        sample_files.extend(filenames)
        break
    the_dir = "Samples"
    paths = [os.path.abspath(os.path.join(the_dir,filename)) for filename in os.listdir(the_dir) if not filename.startswith('.')]    

    sample_directory.append(sample_files)
    sample_directory.append(paths)
    self.sample_directory = sample_directory

    self.sampleChoose_list.clear()
    self.sampleChoose_list.addItems(sample_directory[0])
    self.sampleChoose_list.setSortingEnabled(True);
    self.sampleChoose_list.sortItems()

    return self.sample_directory

def refreshSample_2(self): 
    sample_directory_2 = []
    sample_files_2 = []
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk('./Processed'):
        filenames = [f for f in filenames if not f[0] == '.']
        sample_files_2.extend(filenames)
        break
    the_dir = "Processed"
    paths_2 = [os.path.abspath(os.path.join(the_dir,filename)) for filename in os.listdir(the_dir) if not filename.startswith('.')]    

    sample_directory_2.append(sample_files_2)
    sample_directory_2.append(paths_2)

    processed_info = []
    for i in range(len(sample_directory_2[0])):
        file_info = []
        sample_file_2 = sample_directory_2[0][i]
        sample_path_2 = sample_directory_2[1][i]            
        sample_info_2 = pd.read_excel(ospath(sample_path_2), header = None, sheetname = 3)
        sample_info_2 = sample_info_2.iloc[0][0:3]
        file_info.append(sample_file_2)
        sample_info_2_list = numpy.array(sample_info_2).tolist() 
        file_info.extend(sample_info_2_list)
        processed_info.append(file_info)

    self.clickSample_list.setRowCount(len(processed_info))
    self.clickSample_list.setColumnCount(4)

    labels = ['Имя', 'Массовые отклики', 'Процентранг, %', 'Валидность']
    self.clickSample_list.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(labels)

    red = QtGui.QColor(255, 5, 5);
    orange = QtGui.QColor(255, 157, 0);
    blue = QtGui.QColor(0, 46, 255);


    for row in range(len(processed_info)):
        for column in range(len(processed_info[row])):
            self.clickSample_list.setItem(row, column, QTableWidgetItem(str(processed_info[row][column])))
            if column == 2:
                if processed_info[row][column] > 85:
                    color = red;
                if processed_info[row][column] > 65 and processed_info[row][column] < 85:
                    color = orange;
                if processed_info[row][column] < 65:
                    color = blue;
                self.clickSample_list.item(row, column).setBackground(color);    
    self.clickSample_list.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)


if __name__ == '__main__':
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = MyMainWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

my app is launched in a window and UI is loaded by `from ui_main import Ui_MainWindow`.[image] My question is, how to make a desktop app? Do I need to do it in special Qt5 creator files? Or is possible to make it out of .ipynb-file from Anaconda? I am trying to make both MacOs and Windows versions, but I am pretty new to app-building and programming and do not know, how to begin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cx_Freeze to create a desktop app from a python program.

There's a [guide to packaging a PyQt application](https://www.smallsurething.com/a-really-simple-guide-to-packaging-your-pyqt-application-with-cx_freeze/):

```
cxfreeze-quickstart # generates a creation script
```

On OSX, you have the option of building a .dmg or a .app, by executing one of these at the prompt:

```
python setup.py bdist_dmg
python setup.py bdist_mac
```

On Windows:

```
python setup.py bdist_msi
```

There's a comparison of deployment tools [here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/shipping/freezing/).